# Using an array, I get this error: TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, arrays, integer

So after some trial and error, I think I have my math finally figured out correctly.  Initially, I started this as a set of complex lists, but then found out that the array function is more suited to what I need.

Now that I have established the array, I get this new error:

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)
  File "backandforth3.py", line 118, in (module)
    frames.insert((x+f), (archstartred[x]))
TypeError: list index out of range
```

As I frustratingly yell at the computer that all the data already is an integer, I spare my computer monitor and thought I'd try here.  All the help on here so far has been fantastic.

Here's how I generate the array and the data for the array:  EDIT:  Added the list generator to the program code as it seems to be generating non-integer values.

```
#List Generator

archstartred = []
archstartgrn = []
archstartblu = []

##Red List
for x in range (0, cursorsize):
    if len(archstartred) < cursorsize:archstartred.insert(0,cursred)

for x in range (0, (archnodes-cursorsize)):
    if len(archstartred) < archnodes:archstartred.append(backred)

##Green List
for x in range (0, cursorsize):
    if len(archstartgrn) < cursorsize:archstartgrn.insert(0,cursgrn)

for x in range (0, (archnodes-cursorsize)):
    if len(archstartgrn) < archnodes:archstartgrn.append(backgrn)

##Blue List
for x in range (0, cursorsize):
    if len(archstartblu) < cursorsize:archstartblu.insert(0,cursblu)

for x in range (0, (archnodes-cursorsize)):
    if len(archstartblu) < archnodes:archstartblu.append(backblu)


archstartred = [int(value) for value in archstartred]
archstartgrn = [int(value) for value in archstartgrn]
archstartblu = [int(value) for value in archstartblu]





#Frame Creation

from array import *

frames=array('i', (0 for i in range (0,workingframes*archnodes*3)))






#Frame Population

for f in range (0, workingframes):

    if f<=(workingframes/2):

        for x in range (0, (archnodes*3)):
            frames.pop(x+f)
            frames.insert((x+f), (archstartred[x]))
            frames.pop((x+f)+workingframes)
            frames.insert((x+f+workingframes), (archstartgrn[x]))
            frames.pop((x+f)+workingframes*2)
            frames.insert((x+f+workingframes*2), (archstartblu[x]))

        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop()
            archstartgrn.pop()
            archstartblu.pop()
            archstartred.insert(0, backred)
            archstartgrn.insert(0, backgrn)
            archstartblu.insert(0, backblu)

    else:
        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop(0)
            archstartgrn.pop(0)
            archstartblu.pop(0)
            archstartred.append(backred)
            archstartgrn.append(backgrn)
            archstartblu.append(backblu)

        for x in range (0, (archnodes*3)):
            frames.pop(x+f)
            frames.insert((x+f), (archstartred[x]))
            frames.pop((x+f)+workingframes)
            frames.insert((x+f+workingframes), (archstartgrn[x]))
            frames.pop((x+f)+workingframes*2)
            frames.insert((x+f+workingframes*2), (archstartblu[x]))
```

This is the same program I've been dealing with in my other posts.  Basically, it's to generate data for use in an RGB lighting system.  This "simple" program will generate a back and forth effect using 2 colors.  The other variables include length of time the effect takes, frame size (we use "Sequencers" to generate displays and you can vary the frame size in the sequencer), "cursor" size, etc.

Of course, once I figure out this effect, I'll be able to make more complex effects based on mathematical formulas.

Comment: What line number? Could you post the full traceback message (it would be helpful as it contains more information incl. line numbers)

Comment: What line is giving you the error? Check the error message.

Comment: A point of style, the leading 0 in your range calls in redundant.  Calling range with a single argument assumes you mean to start from 0.

Comment: As the error message indicates, the line that causes the error is this: `frames.insert((x+f), (archstartred[x]))`. Obviously `x` and `f` are integers, because they're defined here as such via the `for` loop, and you never redefine them inside the loop. So `archstartred[x]` must not be an integer. Show us the definition of `archstartred[x]`.

Comment: What's in your `archstartred` array?

Comment: Where in the loops are you failing? First time around? Last time around? Have you walked through it with a [debugger](http://winpdb.org/download/)?

Comment: [archstartred] contains a list of numbers that's generated at the beginning of the program.

Comment: OK, I just ran the program and had it print [archstartred] after the numbers are generated.  It printed this list:  ['255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '255', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ... '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']  I have int statements to get rid of the quotes (or at least I thought it was).  That statement is:  archstartred[x] = [int(value) for value in archstartred[x]]

Comment: @SpencerRathbun it's happening on the first instance.

Comment: Now that I know I have an integer, I'm getting another error.  Edited above.

Comment: I realize I'm coming to this question fairly late, after several answers and edits, but I have to say its completely incomprehensible in its current state. Is there still an answerable question hidden in the code somewhere?

Comment: @Blckknght:  Sorry about that.  Now that we have the values as integers, I'm getting the "list out of range error".  My question is, if the array was built with (workingframes*archnodes*3) values, then the loop statements that populate the array are the same number.

Comment: Figured it out.  I am writing 3 items so I don't need to multiply [archnodes] by 3.  Thanks for everyone's input.  I think I'm getting the hang of it!

Comment: If you've got it solved, you should add your own answer at the bottom, preferably with src pointing out the differences. That way future diggers can see the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your list of integers in quotes `['255', '255', '255', '255', '0']` to `int` properly use this code (you were close):

```
archstartred = [int(value) for value in archstartred]
```

it will yield

```
[255, 255, 255, 255, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's what I get for copying and pasting from other programs!

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be looping x to get all archstartred. Did you write an extra [x]?

I mean, here, this is indented at level 0, outside all loops:

```
for x in range (0, (archnodes-cursorsize)):
   if len(archstartblu) < archnodes:archstartblu.append(backblu)

archstartred[x] = [int(value) for value in archstartred[x]]
archstartgrn[x] = [int(value) for value in archstartgrn[x]]
archstartblu[x] = [int(value) for value in archstartblu[x]]
```

So you only "touch" the very last item (if that) of archstartred, grn, blu. I would have expected either

```
for x in ...
    archstartred[x] = [int(value) for value in archstartred]
```

or

```
archstartred = [int(value) for value in archstartred]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new error means that you are attempting to access a value outside the length of your array. If you have an array of four items `[1, 2, 3, 4]` then `arr[5]`  will fail with your error.

So you are most likely looping too many times around. Otherwise you don't have enough elements in your array.

Comment: Isn't the array set to the correct size?  The loop(s) in the "Frame Population" part of the program is the same as the "Frame Creation" part of the program?  (workingframes*archnodes*3).  I "pop" the data and then "insert" the new value, so the net change to the info in the array is 0.